# How to fix the "Max Retries exceeded with URL" error in Python?

Tags: python, request

I'm having the Max retries exceeded with URL error when trying make requests from different API's. I'm using VSCode with python for a personal/master's project. How can I get it solved?

Tried to use different API's for my purpose, reinstalling packages, reconfigure settings, throwing the try/except into the code, still having the same issue.

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.finnhub.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: ............. (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002A7B4AA02B0>: Failed to resolve 'api.finnhub.io' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))`

Comment: Failed to resolve / getaddinfo means that your computer cannot get the IP address for the host (api.finnhub.io) you are trying to reach.  Issue is fully on your operating system and it's network settings.

Comment: You might be behind a proxy. If you're using a laptop, you can try and go elsewhere and try a different network. If this is a DNS problem, you might be able to solve it by using a different DNS (such as Google's DNS, 8.8.8.8).